# Jenkins/maven configuration recent changes

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm following a udemy class that requires running a build in Maven from a POM.xml file and I have looked here and google for some instructions, but can't find anything that's beginner-level friendly. It seems that Jenkins used to have separate fields for declaring JDK and Maven paths in Manage Jenkins > Configure System and my class still sets the build up like those fields are still there. There is also only freestyle builds as an option when I click new build, apparently there used to be Maven builds.

Here is the screenshot of my configure option on my build:

[image]
C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf has my settings.xml file. There was no settings.xml file in my .m2 directory
If I take C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf out of global settings and use maven default settings, I get this error:

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "test-PRegressionTesting". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException

If I put the global settings in, I get:

[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] The specified global settings file does not exist: C:\Apps\DebitCards
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

JAVA_HOME And M2_HOME are declared in environment variables and I can run the suites called by the profile in pom.xml while running Eclipse, I just can't schedule a Jenkins build without it failing

Can someone at least point me to some decent set up instructions that aren't obsolete? Thanks.

Comment: Usually, one writes a `settings.xml` in the .m2 directory in which you specify which repositories you want to use (and also passwords, if necessary).

Comment: Within Jenkins you use the Config File Provider PLugin which can define a `settings.xml` which also supports the usage for credentials from within the credentials store in Jenkins...Furthermore don't define `M2_HOME`. Furthermore you have to define `test -PSmokeTesting` where the space between `test` and `-PSmokeTesting`  is important.

Comment: Thanks. Is the settings.xml file even necessary? I have my username and password saved in the browser and also in the README on my project

Comment: khmarbaise, this solved my issue, please post as an answer so I can give credit, thank you!